# Representing enum variants with optional data in macro_rules

Tags: enums, rust

I'm trying to create a macro to help with some boilerplate enum code that I've been repetitively writing. I managed to implement a simple enum (i.e. no arguments) relatively easily using a basic `macro_rule`. e.g. An excerpt:

```
macro_rules! enum_helper {
    ($type:ident, { $( $name:ident ), * }) => {
        enum $type {
            $(
                $name,
            )+
        }

        impl FromSql for $type {
            fn from_sql<R: Read>(_: &Type, raw: &mut R, _: &SessionInfo) -> Result<&type> {
                // ... the implementation
        }

        // ... plus some other internal traits being implemented
    }
}

enum_helper!(Step, {
    Step1,
    Step2
});
```

I was hoping to extend this macro to also support a mixed set of enum styles, primarily with only one typed argument e.g.

```
enum_helper!(Step, {
    Step1,
    Step2,
    Step3(i64)
});
```

Is there a way to represent this "optional" argument using `macro_rules`? I suspect it involves using a `tt` however I'm still a bit lost with how `tt` works in a subnested environment.

**Update 1**

I'm using `$name` within some of the trait implementations for pattern matching. For example, I have some code similar to below:

```
match raw {
    $(
        $type::$name => { /* a result of some sort */ },
    )+
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Currently, using your `enum_helper` macro results in more code than directly using `enum`.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear the enum helper is a truncated version of what I'm actually doing. In the actual implementation I am implementing various custom traits etc. I'll update the example to demonstrate.

Comment: Perhaps it would be simpler to only create the `trait`s in the macro, and not creating the `enum` itself?

Comment: Unfortunately, I run into the same problem. Essentially, I'm doing pattern matching against the enum within the trait. I need to match against all scenarios so want to know the given types too. Is it perhaps outside the scope of what a macro can do for now? e.g. a job for AST?

Comment: Where are else are you using `$name`?

Comment: I'm using name for pattern matching. Let me update the example.