# Matching tuple-like enum variants in a macro, where enum type and variants are metavariables: how do I write the matching pattern?

Tags: enums, rust, macros, pattern-matching

Concisely put into Rust code, I'm trying to generate a pattern match like this:

```rust
if let Foo::Variant(_) = value {}
//     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

in a macro, with both `Foo` (a type) and `Variant` (an identifier) passed to the macro as metavariables. In the real use case, I'm generating a `match` instead of an `if let` and am using multiple variants of the same enum, but `if let` resulted in a shorter reproducible example.

This works with simple enums:

```rust
enum Foo {
    Variant,
}

macro_rules! match_enum {
    (
        $value:ident: <$enum:ty>::$variant:ident
    ) => {
        if let <$enum>::$variant = $value {}
    };
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::Variant;
    match_enum!(foo: <Foo>::Variant);
}
```

This compiles.

However, when I make the enum variant tuple-like, it breaks (changes highlighted):

```rust
enum Foo {
    Variant(usize),
//         ^^^^^^^
}

macro_rules! match_enum {
    (
        $value:ident: <$enum:ty>::$variant:ident
    ) => {
        if let <$enum>::$variant(_) = $value {}
//                              ^^^
    };
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo::Variant(0);
//                        ^^^
    match_enum!(foo: <Foo>::Variant);
}
```

```
   |         if let <$enum>::$variant(_) = $value {}
   |                -----------------^^^ unexpected `(` after qualified path
   |                |
   |                the qualified path
...
   |     match_enum!(foo: <Foo>::Variant);
   |     --------------------------------- in this macro invocation
```

I have tried some variations, more or less blindly; `$enum::$variant(_)`, `<$enum::$variant>(_)`, `<$enum::$variant>::(_)` among them.

Is this possible? Am I perhaps using the wrong types of metavariables?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655998/representing-enum-variants-with-optional-data-in-macro-rules) seems to be related, but it focuses on mixing unit and tuple variants, and has not been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by the `$enum` metavariable, as the following slight modifications show:

```rust
macro_rules! match_enum {
    (
        $value:ident: <$enum:ty>::$variant:ident
    ) => {
        // does not fix the problem
        if let <$enum>::Variant(_) = $value {}
        // fixes the problem
        if let Bar::$variant(_) = $value {}
    };
}
```

As the problem happens on the syntax level, we can try change the syntactic makeup of the generated code, in particular by introducing a type alias. We then need to scope that type to not leak out of the macro:

```rust
macro_rules! match_enum {
    (
        $value:ident: <$enum:ty>::$variant:ident
    ) => {
        {
            type Enum = $enum;
            if let Enum::Variant(_) = $value {}
        }
    };
}
```

It's just a workaround, but it's clean enough.